# Is there an example of unitary operator that is not a normal operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible that a unitary operator is not a normal operator?

Comment: What are your definitions in each case and over what field are you working: reals or complex?

Comment: @Timbuc: Unitary is usually reserved for complex spaces. Also I guess unitary means: $U^*U=UU^*=1$

Comment: Oups I accidentally wrote the answer... ^^

Comment: @Sean: It's a good idea with assignments like this in mathematics to start by writing down the definitions involved in the question. So, here, write down the *definition* of a normal operator and the *definition* of a unitary operator. Then you should be able to decide!

Comment: @Freeze, I know that. I was asking the OP to have *from him* his input...but now it's all done

Comment: @SeanCockram The answer is in Freeze's comment: any unitary operator is trivially normal...

Answer (score 6):

$A$ is unitary if (and only if) $A^*A = AA^* = I$.

$A$ is normal if (and only if) $A^*A = AA^*$.

Clearly, if $A$ is unitary, then $A$ is normal.

---

**Points of interest:**

- on infinite-dimensional spaces, isometries (operators satisfying $A^*A = I$) are not necessarily normal.  In fact, an isometry is normal if and only if it is unitary.
- A unitary matrix is not necessarily Hermitian.  A normal matrix is unitary if and only if its eigenvalues have magnitude $1$.  A normal matrix is Hermitian if and only if its eigenvalues are real.  In particular,
  $$
  \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
  $$
  is unitary but not Hermitian (the same can be said about most rotation matrices).

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Some unitary operators are Hermitian.  Some are not.  If an isometry is Hermitian, then it is normal and therefore unitary.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Most unitary operators are not Hermitian (although all are normal).  An easy example is
$$
\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
$$